# How would you translate 「あんまりだぜ神様」?

Tags: meaning, translation

From the lyric of a Vocaloid song, **ナラキスト** by メドミア feat. 初音ミク,

> Ah yeah…  Ah yeah…
> 気を抜けば強制退場命令
> Ah yeah…  Ah yeah…
> **あんまりだぜ神様**
> 俺は俺のもんだろ？

How should I translate the phrase 「あんまりだぜ神様」?

I believe that phrase is asking 'Am I mine?' Perhaps the speaker is asking god, but the あんまだぜ is tripping me up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This あんまり is a na-adjective that means "too harsh/cruel/extreme" or "more than someone deserves". It's typically used when someone needs to be punished but its degree is too much. It's a variation of [余り](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BD%99%E3%82%8A), but I personally think it's better to think of this as a different na-adjective that derived from あまり. People rarely say あまりだぜ in the context in question.

I don't know what this god is trying to do, but 俺は俺のもんだ means something like "I own myself" or "I belong to myself", assuming you have copied it correctly. Maybe this god is trying to take something from this guy.